# How do I use a theme for my lockscreen?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have the "autumn colors in japan" theme and would like the lockscreen to use the same backgrounds.

Specifically - what I want to do is make my lock screen use the same background as the theme I chose through Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Personalization. Currently it's set to Autumn Color in Japan.

Do I have to locate the images and set them manually or is there a way to get the lockscreen to use the background I have for the desktop, set by my theme?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the [microsoft-website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/desktop-background-lock-screen) which shows you, how to do it. You can also set a slideshow as well:

> **To change your lock screen picture**
>
> You can choose just one favorite photo to use as a lock screen
>   picture, or pick a few to create a lock screen slide show.
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap *Settings*, and then tap *Change PC settings*.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click Settings, and then click
>      Change PC settings.)
> 2. Tap or click *PC and devices*, then tap or click *Lock screen*.
> 3. If you want to use just one photo on your lock screen, tap or click Browse, and then choose the picture you want (you can choose photos on
>      your PC or SkyDrive).
> 4. Tap or click the picture you want to use to select it, then tap or click *Choose Image*.
> 5. To play a slide show on your lock screen, tap or click *Play a slide show* on the lock screen to turn it on.
> 6. Tap or click *Add a folder* and browse to the folder where you saved the pictures you want to use.
> 7. Tap or click the folder to select it, tap or click *Choose this folder*, then tap or click *OK*. You can pick up to ten folders

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/desktop-background-lock-screen)

Comment: I already know how to set my own pictures for the lock screen. What I want to do is make my lock screen use the same background as the theme  I chose through Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Personalization. Currently its set to Autumn Color in Japan.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. But You can't change both automatically to the same, at least I don't know any way